# remove today extension from project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

can somebody help me to remove the today extension i've added to my project accidently 
i've tried removing folders and Embedded Binaries but when i want to run

```
Check dependencies Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “*******” were found.
```

this error is given by my today extension named "ExtensionCountdown"

please help me , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove them from `Embedded Binaries`. You will find this in `General` tab in your target.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove extension from application binary.

1.right click your binary and select "Show package content" option.

2.open plugin folder

3. remove .appex file

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the target completely. To do that, remember to enable the "Hide/Show project and target button"

[image]